# How can I do further processing in this rxjs pipeline?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am fetching weather form Yahoo and I want to only grab a few fields out of the response. I thought this might work but it doesn't how can I achieve getting the response JSON and then do some more work to only return an object with a few fields?

```
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getWeather(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .get(this.url)
        .map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
        .switchMap((json) => this.tranformJson(json))
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private tranformJson(json) {
    let result = {};
    const r = json.query.results.channel;
    const current = r.item.condition.temp;
    const f = r.item.forecast[0];
    const { high, low, text} = f;
    result['high'] = high;
    result['low'] = low;
    result['text'] = text;
    result['currentTemp'] = current;
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Don't use switchMap(). Use map(). And create a class or an interface for your result object, so that you can return an Observable<SomethingMeaningful>.

Comment: change your map to this `.map((resp:Response) => this.tranformJson(resp.json()))` and remove your switchMap

Comment: ok combined both of these to properly transform response. Would accept either as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
  getWeather(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .get(this.url)
        .map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
        //You are only using the channel field so pluck it out
        .pluck('query','results','channel')
        // Use map instead of switchMap
        .map(this.transform)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private static transform({item: {forecast, condition}}) {
    const [{high, low, text}] = forecast;
    return {
      currentTemp: condition.temp,
      high,
      low,
      text
    };
  }
```

Comment: This is perfect I didn't know about pluck either which is perfect for this scenario

Comment: Slight error in the code since function marked static it is not this.transform it would be class name. transform

Answer (score 1):

In your transformJson() function you initialize the variable result with an empty object and never assign any values to it. In the end you return and empty result.

Comment: you are correct  I edited my question after I noticed that

Comment: Another problem is that the argument of switchMap is not Observable. 
switchMap is about switching from one observable to another, but your transformJson() returns an object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and pointing that out about switchMap I didn't know that.